# How can a Razor DropDownList GET a pretty URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like the submit in my example code below to GET `/Product/Category/Id`, where the Id value is the selected drop down list id. But instead I'm getting `/Product/Category?Id=Id` and, while it works just fine, doesn't look as nice a URL

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Category", "Product", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div class="category-search">
    <label for="CategoryList">Filter by Category</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CategoryList)
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</div>   
}
```

What do I need to do to keep the pretty URLs

**Edit**
My Global.asax.cs has only the following route mapped

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        // Parameter defaults
);
```

and in my controller I'm adding to the ViewBag *(would prefer to use a ViewModel, but that's already being used with an IPagedList)*

```
var categories = Session.QueryOver<Category>()
                        .OrderBy(c=>c.CategoryName).Asc
                        .List();
ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryName", "CategoryName");
```

I realise it's a bit... odd to use the `CategoryName` for the id and label in the drop down, but I'm using GUIDs for Ids and that makes for an awful URL. This is the only case where being able to 'hack' the URL is valid, i.e. I'm happy for users to type the Category to filter by in the URL if they want, rather than looking it up in the drop down list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you will be able to do what you want to do without capturing the form submit in Javascript, suppressing the default action, extracting the info, building a new action string and submitting the form to that new action string.

The issue is that you are submitting form values, not route parts - the id in the form is entirely different to the id in the route part.  Form variables are always going to go to the server as a GET or Query string when you use `FormMethod.Get`.

Its important to note that its the browser that controls how the form values are submitted back, not the server side MVC code.

Comment: OK, so if I wanted to have the pretty URLs I could get rid of the drop down list and instead put a `<ul>` on the page setting their `ActionLink` as I need?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to hook into the default route which means that you need a lower case `i` in `Id` to match it. Change it to `id` and it should work.

Here's the default route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: I am trying to hook into the default route, but changing the Id to id does not give me the pretty URL I get `/Product/Category?id=Necklace` instead of `/Product/Category/Necklace`

Comment: @SimonMartin Hmm weird, do you have any other routes? Can you post them?

Comment: I'm just using the Default route that came out-of-the-box